# MSBuild search and replace in xml file

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, msbuild

I want to automatically generate a versionCode from a versionName.
I want to remove all dots . and replace X's as 00's

So from 2.05.X.20 -> 2050020

I've started tackeling the X to 00 replacement 
So in the VS csproj file i've added the follwoing BeforeBuild target:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
      <!-- find the versionName in the file -->
      <XmlPeek XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionName">
        <Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="FoundVersionName" />
      </XmlPeek>

        <!-- write the replaced versioncode to the file -->
        <XmlPoke XmlInputPath="Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" Namespaces="&lt;Namespace Prefix='android' Uri='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android' /&gt;" Query="manifest/@android:versionCode" 
          Value="$([System.String]::Copy($(FoundVersionName)).Replace('X','00')) "               />
  </Target>
```

however the output of this looks like

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="$(FoundVersionName)" android:versionName="2.05.X.20" android:installLocation="auto" package="mtdata_taxi_tablet.mtdata_taxi_tablet">
```

i've tried

- $([System.String]::Copy(${FoundVersionName}).Replace('X','00'))
- $([System.String]::Copy($(FoundVersionName)).Replace('X','00'))
- $([System.String]::Copy($FoundVersionName).Replace('X','00'))
- $([System.String]::Copy(@FoundVersionName).Replace('X','00'))
- $([System.String]::Copy(FoundVersionName).Replace('X','00'))

but none of them work

if i use

- $(FoundVersionName)

android:versionCode is replaced with 2.05.X.20

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you used for replacement is correct, however it requires a "property" that is accessible via the `$()` syntax. But your `<XmlPeek>` task is configured to return an item. you can change this by replacing

```
<Output TaskParameter="Result" ItemName="FoundVersionName" />
```

with

```
<Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="FoundVersionName" />
```

Comment: Thank you ! That was it.